# Extract audio from video with FFMPEG but not the same duration

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, extract, duration

My problem is that i need to extract with FFMPEG the audio contained in a video with the same duration. But for some files that i tested, the audio's duration is sometimes shorter than the video's duration. I need to have the exact same duration between the audio and the video file.

The command that i have already tried is this following:

> ffmpeg -i input_video.mp4 output_audio.wav

How can i fix this with options in my command ?

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://superuser.com ?

Comment: Is padding the audio stream with silence acceptable?

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution. To get an audio extract with the exact same length. I use the option `-async 1` like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input_video.mp4 -async 1 output_audio.wav
```

Comment: I tried this option but I still see duration does not match. The gap closed but there is still difference. Any suggestions?