# ffmpeg: video to aligned audio (audio too short)

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I want to extract an aligned audio stream from a video. The goal is to obtain an audio sequence that is **precisely** aligned with the video.

**Issue**: The video and audio sequences are not aligned. The output audio duration is shorter than the video input.

Script to reproduce:

```
fn=TV-20200617-2242-4900.websm.h264
url=https://download.media.tagesschau.de/video/2020/0617/$fn.mp4
wget -nc $url

ffmpeg -y -i "$fn.mp4" -vsync 1 -async 1 -map 0:a "$fn.wav" -map 0:v "$fn.flv"

ffprobe -i $fn.mp4  # Duration: 00:01:51.68
ffprobe -i $fn.flv  # Duration: 00:01:51.68
ffprobe -i $fn.wav  # Duration: 00:01:49.61
```

What I have tried (without success):

- Adding `-async 1` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261283/extract-audio-from-video-with-ffmpeg-but-not-the-same-duration#new-answer).
- Adding `-acodec copy` and exporting the video at the same time ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913032/how-can-i-extract-audio-from-video-with-ffmpeg)).
- Opening the `mp4` in Audacity. The duration there is `00:01:49.61`.
- Opening the `mp4` in VLC. Duration: `00:01:51.68`.
- Explicitly setting the framerate.
- Other video files.

`ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1`

I would appreciate any hint on how to make this work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`ffmpeg` is doing nothing wrong. The input video and audio have slightly different durations:

```
$ ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=codec_type,duration,start_pts,start_time -sexagesimal TV-20200617-2242-4900.websm.h264.mp4 
[STREAM]
codec_type=video
start_pts=3780
start_time=0:00:00.042000
duration=0:01:51.680000
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
codec_type=audio
start_pts=0
start_time=0:00:00.000000
duration=0:01:49.610667
[/STREAM]
```

This does not mean the audio and video are out of sync.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I did not think of this explanation.
I am confused about the meaning of `start_time`. I have another file where `ffprobe` outputs a negative start time for audio: `start_pts=-2048
start_time=0:00:-0.042667`. How can this be?

Comment: @mcb I don't know your audio format and container, but it seems like *priming*, which is normal. See [ffmpeg wrong audio file duration after conversion in AAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42410479/ffmpeg-wrong-audio-file-after-conversion-in-aac).